# cannot push an item to an item array within state

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

How to push an item to an item array within state.The Addcartbutton component adds a new item to **state.items**.But each time when i add new item the **state.items** is not updated.
`

```
    import React from 'react';
    import Addtocartbutton from '../component/addcart';
    import Cart from '../component/cartlist';
    export default class Product extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            items: [],
            total: 0,
            currency: 'INR'
        }
        this.addtocart = this.addtocart.bind(this);
    }

    addtocart(data) {
        console.log(data);
        this.setState({
            items:[this.state.items,data]
        })
        console.log(this.state.items);
    }

    render() {
        var list = this.props.dataname;
        return (
            <div className="card hoverable">
                <div className="card-image">
                    <img src={list.image} alt={list.name} className='shop-img' />
                </div>
                <div className="card-content">
                    <span className="card-title blue-text text-darken-2">{list.price}&nbsp;{list.currency}</span>
                    <p>{list.name}</p>
                </div>
                <Addtocartbutton  onClick={this.addtocart.bind(this,list)} />
            </div>
        )
        return(
        <Cart datalist={this.props.items}/>
       )
      };


     }
```

Tried **this.state.items.push()** but dosen't seems to work at all.Also how to pass item array as a props to Cart component from Product component.

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Cart extends React.Component {

    render() {
        let p = this.props.datalist;
        console.log(p);
        return (
            <ul className="collection">
                <li className="collection-item avatar">
                    <img src="#" alt="" className="circle" />
                    <span className="title">dfdfd</span>
                    <a href="#!" className="secondary-content"><i className="material-icons">grade</i></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this it may help

```js
addtocart(data) {
    console.log(data);
    let items = this.state.items.slice();
    items.push(data);
    this.setState({
        items:items
    }, ()=> {
      console.log(this.state.items);
    })
    
}
```

Steps of method

1- first i create a new variable from this.state.items.slice() which will return new array instance.

2- simply push the data into the array and set the state of items

3- Arrays are reference type in javascript, to update the state you have to pass a new array thus I am passing the new items array (let items = this.state.items.slice();)

Answer (score 0):

you can't mutate directly as `this.state.push`  but you need to extend the object

```
 addtocart(data) {
        console.log(data);
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            items:[...prevState.items, data]
        }))
    }
```

Example code:

[image: Edit 1qyzx71ovq]

Comment: "doesn't work" isn't helpful. What specifically is the issue when you try it? The exact issue, error messages, etc.

Comment: For Milos' answer, you'll need to have the proper plugin for transpiling the spread/rest operator

Comment: prevState = this.state.items;
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            items:[prevState,data]
        }))
 is this correct ??

Comment: only one item is present within the items array.Still the array is not getting updated after each click.

Comment: No because you're setting the old state EQUAL to the new one. You need to create a _copy_ of old state values you use if they are arrays/objects. Try something like `this.setState({items:this.state.items.slice().concat(data)})`

Comment: Also you're trying to `console.log(this.state.items);` right after, but `setState()` is *asynchronous*, so the change won't show if you print it on the next line. Try printing the items in the render function

Comment: @lx6002 my code works, I've sent it in codeSandbox example and edited my answer.

Comment: @jayce444 Still it's showing only one item within the array.The length of the array is still showing 1.

Comment: @lx6002 did you check my example? It's showing the items correctly, and they are pushed to the array as you wanted in your example.

Comment: @MilosMosovsky yes it is working.But how to send item array as a prop to cart component after the item is pushed to the state.items.

Comment: `<Cart items={this.state.items} />`

Comment: @MilosMosovsky can you do it using my code above ??

Comment: I can't. At first you didn't provide `Cart` component so I can't do it, and 2nd, did you even try by yourself ?

Comment: @MilosMosovsky i have passed item array as props to cart component.please look the above code.

Comment: You have 2 returns ... you can't have 2 returns from any javascript function return is just one, you need to add it to the first return

Comment: buddy, you can't comment 50 seconds later after someone tries to guide you to show you a code, SO is not a coding service. Same as you did `<AddtocartButton>` you will add `<Cart>` below that line

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is with the onClick on the addtocartbutton component. Just have the onClick function as 
`<Addtocartbutton  onClick={this.addtocart(list)} />`
and follow the code given by Milos. (I wish I could comment on the first answer, but I do not have enough reputation).

Also, the addtocart method is already bound in the constructor, so there is no need to bind it again.

Answer (score 0):

As `addtocart` is already binded in the constructor, no need to bind it again. so update your code as below.

```
<Addtocartbutton onClick={this.addtocart(list)} />
```

and update your `addtocart` method as shown below. (I have used [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) concept here)

```
addtocart(data) {
  return function() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        items:[...prevState.items, data]
    }))
  }.bind(this)  
}
```

or use the below code which uses the arrow functions.

```
addtocart = data => () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      items: [...prevState.items, data]
    }));
  };
```